Why are questions summarily locked?
The questioner wanted to know about this syntax:

The sentence is: "Could we have found a buyer who would continue operations, I would have certainly preferred to sell the business rather than liquidate it."

I just spent about ten minutes looking for a good example to support an answer,  only to find that my answer couldn't be posted because the question had been summarily locked.  Why is someone pouncing on questions in that manner? What specific features of a question qualify it as lock-worthy?

Yes, that is an alternate form of conditional statement that doesn't rely on if. But starting a sentence with a modal verb in that manner is rather old-fashioned.

We did not then know that this movement was but the opening of the siege of Port Hudson, in which the One Hundred and Sixteenth was destined to play as important a part as the men we envied, and that while Emory's Division could inscribe on their battle flags "Fort Bisland," and Grover's Division "Irish Bend," Augur's Division would soon be enabled to inscribe on theirs "Plain Store." Could we have foreseen it, we should have been better contented with our seemingly unfortunate lot.
The One Hundred and Sixteenth Regiment of New York State Volunteers: Being a Complete History of Its Organization and of Its Nearly Three Years of Active Service in the Great Rebellion. To which is Appended Memorial Sketches and a Muster Roll of the Regiment, Containing the Name of Every Man Connected with it
By Orton S. Clark, 1868


It was migrated via community vote, locking the copy here on ELU. Please answer on ELL: "Could" at the beggining of a non-question sentence

Please answer on ELL a question about a barely grammatical antiquated subject-auxiliary-inversion could-conditional? Vous etes joking me, surement?
